# WebGL sometimes draws solid color rather drawing a quad

Tags: javascript, glsl, webgl

Hi I was trying to render a quad and sometime it renders the quad with uv coordinate properly and sometime don't, while I use the console log trick the render loop still working but with no color it just blank black and I quite new to WebGL. I have been searched on google but nothing worked I'm only having a unity one than the real answer what I'm looking for I tried using `gl.drawElement` and still have same result on my editor webview when on my android browser chrome it works like normal. Here is my code :

````
<html>
    <head>
        <title>WebGL</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
            #glCanvas {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body onload="main();">
        <canvas id="glCanvas"></canvas>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function main() {
                var canvas = document.querySelector("#glCanvas");
                var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
            
                if(gl == null) {
                    alert("Unable to initialize WebGL. Your browser or machine may not support it.");
                    return;
                }
                
                canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                gl.viewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                
                var vertexShaderSc = `
                    precision highp float;
                    precision highp int;
                    
                    attribute vec2 position;
                    
                    void main(void) {
                        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
                    }
                `;
                
                var fragmentShaderSc = `
                    precision highp float;
                    precision highp int;
                    uniform vec2 resolution;
                    uniform float time;
                    
                    void main(void) {
                        vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy/resolution.xy;
                    
                        gl_FragColor = vec4(uv+time, 0.0, 1.0);
                    }
                `;
                
                var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
                var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
                gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSc);
                gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSc);
                
                gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
                if(!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                    console.error("Error compiling vertex shader", gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
                    return;
                }
                gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
                if(!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
                    console.error("Error compiling fragment shader", gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
                    return;
                }
                
                var program = gl.createProgram();
                gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
                gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
                gl.linkProgram(program);
                if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
                    console.error('ERROR linking program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
                    return;
                }
                gl.validateProgram(program);
                if(!gl.getProgramParameter(program, gl.VALIDATE_STATUS)) {
                    console.error('ERROR validating program!', gl.getProgramInfoLog(program));
                    return;
                }
                
                var vertex_data = [ 
                    // First triangle:
                     1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0,  1.0,
                    -1.0, -1.0,
                    // Second triangle:
                    -1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0, -1.0,
                     1.0,  1.0];
                var buffer0 = gl.createBuffer();
                gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer0);
                gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(vertex_data), gl.STATIC_DRAW);
                
                var positionAttrib = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "position");
                gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionAttrib, 2, gl.FLOAT, gl.FALSE, 2 * Float32Array.BYTES_PER_ELEMENT, 0);
                gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionAttrib);
                
                gl.useProgram(program);
                var resolutionUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "resolution");
                gl.uniform2fv(resolutionUniform, new Float32Array([canvas.width, canvas.height]));
                var timeUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "time");
                var frameUniform = gl.getUniformLocation(program, "frame");
                
                function render(timeStamp) {
                    gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, timeStamp*0.001);
                    gl.uniform1i(frameUniform, timeStamp);
                    gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
                    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
                    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);
                    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
                    requestAnimationFrame(render);
                }
                requestAnimationFrame(render);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

This fault is pretty funny because I should call the loop function rather requesting out from the function, so here is what I wanted. Responsive canvas and have a time function so first create event listener and after that update the canvas resolution and webgl viewport and the uniform updates such as resolution. So this is the code :

```
window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);
function onWindowResize() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    gl.viewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    gl.uniform2fv(resolutionUniform, new Float32Array([canvas.width, canvas.height]));
}
```

And for the renderer loop will be like this :

```
function render(timeStamp) {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    gl.uniform1f(timeUniform, timeStamp*0.001);
    gl.uniform1i(frameUniform, timeStamp);
    gl.clear(gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
}
render();
```